# MySQL ORDER BY numeric value problem with negative numbers

Tags: mysql

I am using a query which uses:

```
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

'score' just holds numeric values, which can also be negative. They don't seem to be displaying in the correct order. The negative numers can appear above positive numbers.

Does anyone know the query I should use to display them like this:

- 10
- 5
- 1
- -1
- -5
- -10

And also to stop them doing this:

```
* 1
* 10
* 11
* 123
* 1234
* 2
* 25
* 253
* 34
```

Thanks.

Comment: What date type is `score`. It holds numeric values, but it the **column type** numeric?

Comment: Seems not. Those results are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I would bet the `score` column is textual, not numeric...

Comment: I try to make it numeric but it goes to *decimal(10,0)*

Comment: The result I put in my question was an example, not a result that I am receiving.

Comment: It seems that no one can replicate your result. Suggest you provide a sqlfiddle and/or DDLs for us to play with.

Answer (score 5):

```
order by cast(score as int) desc;
```

It appears that you are storing numeric data in a string data type.  It would be better to make score a numeric data type, like `int`.

Comment: 'score' is *int* in my database.

Comment: Yes
`$query = "SELECT message,`score`,ip,date,name,website,id FROM `messages` WHERE deleted=0 AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)ORDER BY `score` DESC"; `

Comment: Should I use `"ORDER BY ABS(score) DESC"`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?  What happened?

Comment: Can you script out the database and post somewhere? See for example @Logan's answer. If you follow @Logan's code, do you have the same problem? What collation are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to order by a cast varchar by casting the field using:

```
ORDER BY CAST(`table.field` AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Where SIGNED will turn the varchar to a integer (which can be a negative value).

A guide is available here: http://www.kreci.net/web-development/sort-varchar-as-int-in-mysql-query/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for except I want ASC in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype for score is probably a char type. Properly specifying your datatype as a signed integer or decimal with the proper precision will make this problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any issues getting the negative numbers to be ordered from greatest to least...  Here's my CREATE code and query, for your reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `score` INT(10) NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

select * from test order by score desc;
```

And the dump from my database:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (-5);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (-10);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (-11);
INSERT INTO `test` (`score`) VALUES (7);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CAST('name_of_field' AS SIGNED) DESC;
```

In your case name_of_field is score so:

```
ORDER BY CAST('score' AS SIGNED) DESC;
```